# Simple Boolean Algebra Exercise but stuck

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have the following exercise that I can't really solve or I am not happy with the result:

> - If Team A loses, Team B and C will lose too
> - If the Teams A and B win, Team C will lose
> - If Team B wins, Team A will win too and Team C will lose
> - If the Teams B or C lose, Team A will lose too.
>
> How will the games end if these prognoses are right?

First I created the implications and resolved them so that I got
$$(A+\overline{BC})*(\bar A+\bar B+\bar C)*(\bar B+A\bar C)*(BC+\bar A)$$

I came to the following result:
$$A\bar BC+\bar A\bar B\bar C$$

That would mean that either A wins, B loses and C wins or all the teams lose.
But as the last condition is "If the Teams B or C lose, Team A will lose too, this has to be wrong and I think all teams lose.
I just can't figure out how to prove this with boolean algebra.

Hope, somebody can help here. Thanks!

Edit: My mistake - just tried it again and the result is as expected:
$$\bar A \bar B \bar C$$

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Feel free to write up your correct work as an answer :)